# how to stop : Flutter Console from printing [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102] in debug mode?

Tags: flutter

lately when I run my flutter app in debug I'm getting all the time this message that says :

```
[ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
```

and it's keep on printing on this agin and agin in the console.

so what is the cause of this? and how do I stop it?

Comment: This could be because your machine and your testing device are running on two different networks.

Comment: please do explain more I didn't get the full idea 

my laptop and phone are working on the same network(WIFI)

or do you mean something else? @theEUG

Answer (score 9):

change the device.

that's the Huawei Issue. if you change the device this message will disappear. after some digging I found that Huawei added something, so that's why we are seeing this.